# Changing CPU affinity on they fly has no result

Tags: linux, process, python, cpu, priority

so I am creating my own script to set priority and cpu affinity for important processes on my system, and I tried using taskset command, but it seems to do nothing.

Here's sample:

```
import psutil
import os
import sys

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    command = "taskset -cp 0 "+str(proc.pid)
    os.system(command)
```

I run this python script as root, and it gives output like this (for every process on my system):

```
pid 5893's current affinity list: 0,1
pid 5893's new affinity list: 0
```

I have CPU with 12 threads, and no matter how I play around with this command still all cores are used as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work for multithreaded applications - try adding `-a` to the list of arguments.

```
       -a, --all-tasks
           Set or retrieve the CPU affinity of all the tasks (threads) for a given PID.
```